# How do I save the Oracle in God of War?

Tags: god-of-war

So the Oracle is hanging from the rope screaming at me to save her, and I can't figure out how to get to the ledge.

From the looks of things, I have to scale around everything, but I don't know how to start. Everywhere I see is either too high to reach or too far to jump.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is what you do.

1. Drag the statue near the entrance and place it on the elevator. (It is constantly moving up and down)
2. Get the other statue and stack it on top of this one when the elevator goes down.
3. Drag the stacked statues to the water fountain.
4. Climb on top of the small temple thingy and jump towards the hanging vines.
5. From here it is straight forward to the oracle. (you have about a minute)